# get Recursive field values in GORM

Tags: go, recursive-query, go-gorm

I have a category table where has a recursive field named children. A parent may have child/children.

```
type Category struct {
    ID uint
    Name string
    ParentID *uint `gorm:"index" json:"parent_id"`
    Children []Category `gorm:"foreignkey:ParentID"`
}
```

when i use `DB.Preload("Children").Find(&Category)` i get only first children field, but that children have also many children more. how can I get all fields until children have no more children?

if you make a query for me that will be better for me understanding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The query you are making is of the sort:

```
SELECT * FROM Category;
SELECT * FROM Children WHERE id IN (<your categories>);
```

this seems to be all good, except you don't have an entity Children, it is a field on the same Category table, if you just

```
var categories []Category;
DB.Find(&categories);
```

you should get all the categories from your table, from there you can filter things with `Where()` and such.

since you want all children from a category you could query with:

```
var categories []Category;
parentCategoryID := 1;
DB.Where("parentID = ?", parentCategoryID).Find(&categories);
```

this should yield all the categories that are children of a single parent.

You could go through each of those children and repeat the call to find all of their children and you could add them to a slice to flatten the data.

```
// continuing from previous code snippet
var flatCategories []Category;
for _, category := range categories {
    var tempCategories []Category;
    DB.Where("parentID = ?", category.ID).Find(&tempCategories);
    flatCategories = append(flatCategories, tempCategories...);
}
```

[reference for querying with gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html)

[how preloading works with gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload)

Answer (score 0):

```
DB.Preload("Category.Category.Category").Find(&Category)
```

It works for me.
Looks like need to pass the depth into the Preload func.